# How to hide only android software navigation buttons

Tags: android

I know about the immersive mode in android, but the thing is that I want to hide only android software navigation buttons, so status bar should not dissappear. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION)

I linked the documentation, but basically you just need to set this flag in the onCreate method.